# Differentiablity of bi-dimensional function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ of class $C^{1}$, show that the function $F:\mathbb{R^{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable if $x \neq y$. Also show that that if $f$ is of class $C^{2}$, then F is differentiable in all $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

The function F is given by:

$
F=\begin{cases} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}, x\neq y \\
f'(x), x=y
\end{cases}
$

Comment: What have you tried? These details should be in your post to attract answers.

Comment: Well I'm pretty much stuck with this one, I had a couple of health problems and couldn't attend some of my calculus classes, hence I'm not really yup to date with the material

Comment: No time like the present to get caught up :) Do you have any definitions? What does it mean for F to be differentiable/what theorems about differentiability has your class proven. Then try to apply them directly.

Comment: As I've said I haven't been to my classes for a while, so I don't know what he proved or didn't, that's why I've asked this here.

Comment: well then you're kind of stuck between a rock and a hard place because there are many different answers we could give you, but only the "age-appropriate" one will be useful to you. This topic of higher dimesnional differentiability is tackled very differently between intro classes and real analysis classes and even within the same difficulty level the formulations between professors can be wildly different. You need to get notes from a friend or talk to the professor themselves.

Comment: This class is supposed to be a kind of real analysis in higher dimensions. I've been thinking of considering the limit in the definition of differentiability but then I kind of get stuck, any tips of some sort ?

Comment: As long as $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$, are there any singularities away from the line $x=y$? And how does the assumption of continuous second derivative smooth the singularity at that critical line when you do attempt to take the limit?

Comment: What do you mean by singularities?

Comment: places where the function blows up

Comment: Could you just post a sketch of a solutioin please, I'm really busy and don't really have the time to keep updating the post and discusting the question. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can tell that for $x\neq y$ the function $F$ is differentiable because it is a quotient of two differentiable functions and the denominator is not zero.

To prove that if $f\in C^2$ then $F$ is differentiable, it is enough to prove that $F$ is differentiable on the line $x=y$. The other points we already know.

Let's look at the point $(x_0,x_0)$ on that line. At that point, for $h_1\neq h_2$,

$$Q=\frac{\left|F(x_0+h_1,x_0+h_2)-F(x_0,x_0)-D\right|}{|h_1|+|h_2|}=\frac{\left|\frac{f(x_0+h_2)-f(x_0+h_1)}{h_2-h_1}-f'(x_0)-D\right|}{|h_1|+|h_2|}$$

Since $f\in C^2$ we can write $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)h+f''(x_0)h^2/2+o(|h|^2)$ the last fraction for $Q$ is equal to

$$\frac{\left|f''(x_0)(h_1+h_2)-D+\frac{o(|h_2|^2)-o(|h_1|^2)}{h_2-h_1}\right|}{|h_1|+|h_2|}$$

So, taking $D$ to be the function $D(h_1,h_2)=f''(x_0)(h_1+h_2)/2$, which is linear in $(h_1,h_2)$ we get that the quotient $Q$ above tends to $0$ as $(h_1,h_2)\to0$ along $h_1\neq h_2$.

Finally, along $h_1=h_2$ we have that the quotient $Q$ is 
$$\frac{\left|f'(x_0+h_1)-f'(x_2)-D\right|}{|h_1|+|h_2|}$$

By taking $D$ as before, which on $h_1=h_2$ is becomes $f''(x_0)h_1$, we get that $Q$ tends to $0$ as $h_1\to 0$.

Combining the two limits we get that tending $(h_1,h_2)$ in any fashion, with the choice of differential $D(h_1,h_2)=f''(x_0)(h_1+h_2)/2$ the function $F$ satisfies [the definition of differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) at $(x_0,x_0)$.